# Disable IPV6 on specific NIC via PowerShell using a Com Object on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, wmi, ipv6

I need to script some Windows Server 2008 R2 builds, preferably in PowerShell.  I need to disable or uncheck IPV6 on a specific NIC (the same NIC every time).  Currently, I have to set it manually.  I do not want to disable IPV6 completely for the entire server other things may use that in the future.  Is there an object I can reference in a PowerShell command specifying my NIC "Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection" and disable IPV6?  Unfortunately, Group Policy is not an option says the boss.  I've tried finding an appropriate WMI object via "PowerShell Scriptomatic" but failed to find the difference between an enabled setting versus disabled on the Intel NIC. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate with: http://serverfault.com/questions/257118/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-a-particular-network-interface-using-server-core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First before removing IPV6 you'better read these Microsoft articles :

[How to disable IP version 6 (IPv6)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852/en-us)

[What are Microsoft's recommendations about disabling IPv6?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/cc987595.aspx)

In summary you can disable IPV6 on all interfaces using (detailled explanation [here](http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/enabling-or-disabling-ipv6.html)):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\TCPIP6\Parameters]
“DisabledComponents”=dword:ffffffff
```

---

Edited

According to @David Brabant comment to desable IPV6 on only one adapter you can bind or unbind it with the registry key :

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip6\Linkage]
"Bind"=RegmultiSZ
```

of the form :

```
\Device\{DBB82A20-A485-4CB6-AD31-EF14B91F5EFB}
```

You can build this line with :

```
# Public Name NetworkCard Name
$networkCardName = "Connexion au réseau local 1"

# Get Device GUID
$guid=(gwmi -query "select * from win32_networkadapter where netconnectionid= '$networkCardName'").guid
```

Comment: The OP is trying to disable it on a single NIC rather than globally.

Comment: Read the articles : disabling IPV6 as it's asked in the question is just not recommended by Microsoft on a production machine.

Comment: The only thing I saw that might be a reason not to disable it was "If you disable IPv6, you will not be able to use Windows Meeting Space or any application that relies on the Windows Peer-to-Peer Networking platform or the Teredo transition technology.". I didn't see anything advising not to disable it for a specific interface.

Comment: Just read the second link : From Microsoft's perspective, IPv6 is a mandatory part of the Windows operating system and it is enabled and included in standard Windows service and application testing during the operating system development process. Because Windows was designed specifically with IPv6 present, Microsoft does not perform any testing to determine the effects of disabling IPv6. If IPv6 is disabled on Windows 7 or later versions, some components will not function. Moreover, applications that you might not think are using IPv6—such as Remote Assistance, HomeGroup, DirectAccess,

Comment: I see. The applications listed are all desktop apps though. The OP is looking to configure Win Server so there may be no issues. Perhaps changing the setting to prefer IPv4 might be safer.

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft has a command line program nvspbind (https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Hyper-V-Network-VSP-Bind-cf937850), that can disable ipv6 on a specific interface.  It seems to be identical to unchecking the IPv6  box in adapter settings dialog.  You can launch this program from a script or your program.

The command line arguments to disable IPv6 on a particular interface is:

```
nvspbind -d {GUID} ms_tcpip6
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as nvspbind works without the need for a reboot or logout/login. You do not even need to provide the {GUID}, it works also with the name of the network interface. I use this command to get the names of the network interfaces: wmic nic get NetConnectionID

Comment: THANK YOU. This is exactly what I needed. The same 32-bit binary works from Windows 7 to German Windows 10. It's perfect!

Answer (score -2):

I use simple .bat files with the "netsh" command.  You can certainly use "netsh" with Powershell, if you prefer.

Comment: Care to describe how you did it?